# Create MD5 hash in Python based on PHP code

Tags: python, md5

Code in PHP I need to move to python

`[md5 key] = md5( ( [Request Timestamp] % [Registration Window] ) . [salt] );`

Example:

```
<?php
function get_md5_hash($strDatetime, $strAuthWindow, $strSalt) {
return md5((strtotime($strDatetime) % ((int)$strAuthWindow)) .$strSalt);
}
print get_md5_hash("2013-04-29T20:51:29GMT+0300", "604800", "155961");
?>
```

Python code this far

```
timestamp = datetime.datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=6)
timestamp_str = '{:%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S}'.format(timestamp)

salt = "454243"
registration_window = "604800"

import hashlib

md5_key = hashlib.md5(((timestamp_str % registration_window) .salt).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
```

I can't get past this error message:

> TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after another ~2 weeks of trying to find a solution I still don't have a working python code that will generate the required md5 hash. However I do have a "hack" solution that did work so I'll post that here already and will update in case I find a python solution.

What I did was run the forumla in PHP and import the solution into my python code.

utils.py

```
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.Popen("php md5.php", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
script_response = proc.stdout.read()

script_response1 = script_response.decode().split('|')[0]
```

md5.php

```
<?php

$strAuthWindow = 604800;
$strSalt = "454243";

function get_md5_hash($strDatetime, $strAuthWindow, $strSalt) {
return md5((strtotime($strDatetime) % ((int)$strAuthWindow))
.$strSalt);
}

print("$strDatetime");
print get_md5_hash("$strDatetime,", "$strAuthWindow", "$strSalt");

?>
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue you're facing basically boils down to `timestamp_str` and `registration_window` being strings. In Python, one way to format strings is using the `%` operator. For example,

```
def sayGreeting(name):
    return "Hello %s" % name
```

This operator on strings is different than the operator you want to use which is the modulus operator that computes the remainder of two integers.

The `strtotime` function in PHP returns an integer which is the Unix Timestamp of the string representation of a date and time. To get the same results in Python, you need to convert your timestamp to a Unix Timestamp integer, as well.

Concatenation of strings in PHP is done using the `.` operator. However, in Python, this is the `+` operator. This is why you need to change `.salt` to `+ salt` because you're concatenating the salt to the Unix Timestamp.

I wrote some code to help you get started.

```
import datetime
import time
import hashlib

timestamp = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(hours=6)
unix_time = time.mktime(timestamp.timetuple())

salt = "454243"
registration_window = 604800

resulting_timestamp = str(unix_time % registration_window)

md5_digest = hashlib.md5(resulting_timestamp + salt).hexdigest()
```

Remember to never use MD5 for any application where security is a concern. It is **not** a secure hash function.

Comment: I would update that to "never use MD5".  If security is not a concern, there are much faster hash functions; if it is, MD5 is not secure.

Comment: Ya security is not too important, we just need to submit a POST and they verify incoming POSTs this way. What you wrote above definitely makes sense. However, now I get the "Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing" error. I then tried to add the ".encode('utf-8')" like it was before but no luck.

Answer (score 2):

use this

```
md5_digest = hashlib.md5((resulting_timestamp + salt).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.